# PHP 4 - variables inside class

Tags: php, class, variables, php4

I have a class like

```
class blah extends blahblah{

  private $variable = '5';

  function somefunction(){
    echo $variable;
  }
}
```

this works in php 5, but not in php 4.
I get a error:

```
Parse error: parse error, unexpected
T_VARIABLE, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION
or T_FUNCTION or T_VA....
```

I also tried with `public` and `static`. Same error.

How can I add a variable inside that class that I can access from all class functions?

Comment: The *most important question* is, why do you still care about PHP4?

Comment: Please upgrade to modern PHP version, PHP 4 is dead for 2.5 years now. Let it rest in peace.

Comment: I don't, but the application that has this function won't run only on my site

Comment: So? Then make a requirement, *needs PHP5*. This is only fair these days. PHP4 is indeed dead, most servers will run PHP5. And if not: Not your problem!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

private is not a valid keyword in PHP 4 change it to `var $variable = '5';`
also the function is wrong it should be...

```
class blah extends blahblah{

  var $variable = '5';

  function somefunction(){
    echo $this->variable;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In PHP4, member variables are declared with `var`:

```
var $variable = '5';
```

But you still have to access it via `$this->variable` in your function <del>(I think, I'm not so familiar with PHP4)</del>.

That said, if possible, upgrade! PHP4 and "OOP" is more pain than fun.

**Update:** Ha, found it, some documentation about [***Classes and Objects in PHP4***](http://www.php.net/manual/en/oop4.php).

Comment: +1 But, I'm not really sure PHP4's "OOP" can be called OOP, it's more like structs than OOP really. ;)

Comment: @netcoder: True... in the documentation they say *Classes and Objects*... not mentioning OOP either ;D